# How to recurse through arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm trying to use the two following methods to recursively traverse arrays of arrays until the bottom and then come back up with the match results.

You know how in a tennis tournament they start with 32 matches and pair by pair the winner moves ahead, and at the end there's only one winner? That's what I want to replicate in Ruby.

I created a `match_winner` that always returns the first array for the sake of simplicity.  Then, I send the whole tournament array into `winner` that calls itself recursively until it finds a simple array corresponding to a single match.

```
def match_winner(array_of_arrays)
  return array_of_arrays[0]
end

def winner(tournament)
  if tournament[0][0].is_a?(String)
    return match_winner(tournament)
  else
    tournament.each{|e|
      winner(e)
    }
  end
end

tournament = [
  [["one", "two"],["three", "four"]],
  [["five", "six"],["seven", "eight"]]
  ]

puts winner(tournament).inspect
```

Which outputs:

```
[[["one", "two"], ["three", "four"]], [["five", "six"], ["seven", "eight"]]]
```

I tried different permutations and variations on this algorithm but I couldn't make it work correctly and return only the final winner.

Does anyone see anything obviously wrong here?

---

Now I'm calling `winner`.

Comment: You're not calling `winner` at all...

Comment: so ['one', 'two'] is a game and 'two' is the winner right ?

Comment: You're calling #match_winner, which you've hard coded to always return the first value. Presumably you meant to call `p winner(tournament)`.

Comment: Seems like you want to solve Rock-Paper-Scissor problem :). If so, then what exactly you want?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly. This has been bugging me for days now.

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: Yes, what output do you want?

Comment: Well, I just want a recursive way to return the tournament winner, the input being that array and also higher orders of it... like an upside-down binary tree I guess...i think that's the best description.... perhaps I'm getting confused about the recursive calls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want `map`, not `each`, and, as a commenter above notes, you didn't call `winner` in the above code.

When you call:

```
tournament.each {...}
```

that method actually returns the tournament, which is thus what `winner` returns.

What you want is to replace it with

```
tournament.map {...}
```

which returns a new array consisting of calling "winner" on each element of tournament.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question looks like it's answered, but I just did the same problem and I have to say that simply changing `each` to `map` didn't work for me, because, as the code posted, the result is an array of the first-round winners. What worked for me is:

```
def winner(tournament)
  if tournament[0][0].is_a?(String)
    return match_winner(tournament)
  else
    tournament.map!{|e| #use map!, because we need to apply winner() to new values
      e=winner(e)       #assign new value somewhere, so recursion can climb back
    }
  end
end
```

Maybe more experienced developers can explain why that is. Without these two tips it won't work.

And yes, I know "bang" is a bad coding style, danger danger high voltage, but it's my second day with Ruby and I wanted to get this to work.

And, to understand recursion, you have to understand recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2^n number of games always and `match_winner` works ok:

```
def winner(game)
  if game[0][0][0] == game[0][0][0][0]
    match_winner( [ game[0], game[1] ] )
  else
    match_winner( [winner(game[0]), winner(game[1])] ) 
  end
end
```

Comment: what's the tournament variable? Is it an external variable? shouldn't it be `game`?

Comment: But why 3 levels? I mean, why [0][0][0] ? An Array, according to my rules, is a valid single match if arr[0][0].is_a?(String)... Right?

Comment: in your example arr[0][0] is ["one", "two"]. arr[0][0][0] is "one".

Comment: see my updated answer. it is working but dont ask me what is game[0][0][0] == game[0][0][0][0] because I have no idea :) found it while trying.